# findViewById() returns null in TabActivity class

Tags: android

I have NewTransferActivity class, which extends TabActivity. The code:

```
public class NewTransferActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.account_transfer);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("receiver").setIndicator("Rec").setContent(getReceiverTab());
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("transfer").setIndicator("Trans").setContent(getTransferTab());
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}

private TabContentFactory getReceiverTab(){
    TabContentFactory factory = new TabContentFactory() {
        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {

            ...

            return layout;
        }
    };
    return factory;
}

private TabContentFactory getTransferTab(){
    TabContentFactory factory = new TabContentFactory() {

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytrans);

            if (layout == null){
                //layout = new LinearLayout(NewTransferActivity.this);
                System.out.println("NULL>>>>>>");
                return new LinearLayout(NewTransferActivity.this);
            }
            return layout;
        }
    };
    return factory;
} ...
```

my xml file, which contains layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mytrans"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to load layout for a single tab from xml file which I definded. Unfortunatelly I am getting NullPointerException because layout is null in method getTransferTab(). 'LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytrans)' returns null. What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather try to use `LayoutInflater` to get the view hierarchy from the xml,

```
    TabContentFactory factory = new TabContentFactory() {
        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {

             LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Activity_Name.this);
             View linearLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mytrans, null);

            return linearLayout;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Perfect answer, but insread R.id.mytrans I had to use R.layout.layout_name. Big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts are that, in this line:

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytrans);
```

you are calling the `findViewById` method of your `TabContentFactory`

You need to call the version of that command that is located in the `Activity`.

Comment: Hi. I have changed this line to LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) NewTransferActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.mytrans); but the result is still null. I have also tried to write a method in my activity class which simply returns a LinearLayout: private LinearLayout idRes(){ LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytrans);  return layout; } and called it in getReceiverTab() but it isn`t correct

Comment: Call findViewById directly after SetContentView to ensure that you are getting the correct view. Maybe you are loading the wrong layout.